# Opening a div from navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I would like to open a div when clicking on the button, at the moment the div opens when I hover over a button, but i need to open it when clicking on it .I have never used java script before, so I guess that's what I need for the click on button. Can someone help me on doing that using the code below. I hope I don't have to change to whole website for doing that operation

```
<html lang ="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main1.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/slide.css" media="all">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript">
var tday=new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

function GetClock(){
var d=new Date();
var nday=d.getDay(),nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate();
var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds(),ap;

if(nhour==0){ap=" AM";nhour=12;}
else if(nhour<12){ap=" AM";}
else if(nhour==12){ap=" PM";}
else if(nhour>12){ap=" PM";nhour-=12;}

if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin;
if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;

document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tday[nday]+", "+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+ap+"";
}

window.onload=function(){
GetClock();
setInterval(GetClock,1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:0;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}



/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}

.box{
background-color:#ffe680;
width:895px;
height:500px;
position:fixed;
margin-top:154px;
margin-left:288px;
z-index:1;
}


  h1 {
  color:white;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px red;
} 

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:1;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:96px;
    width:800;
    height:500;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #F28686;
}
setTimeout( function(){$('box').hide();} , 4000);

</style>







<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" style="margin-left:208px;">News</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content"style="margin-left:325;">
  <h1 style="margin-left:50;">Cooperate news</h1>
  <ul style="float:left; margin-right:60%;margin-top:-10;line-height:2;list-

style:none;">

      <li> <a href="http://www.molex.com/molex/home"> *How connected cars are turning into revenue-generating machines - August 29, 2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">*Delphu, Mobileye Join Forces to Develop Selfdrive System - August 23,2016</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">*MIT Spinoff to Market Breakthrough Batteries by 2017 - August 22,2016</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">*Cisco Cuts Workforce by 7 percent to Speed Transition to Software - August 18, 2016</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1 style="margin-left:490; margin-top:-60;">Chengdu News</h1>
      <ul style="margin-left: 55%; margin-top:-396;float:left; line-height:2;list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <a href="#">* 10 Year Service Award ceremony</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">* PDP Training</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">* ISO 27001 project Kick-off</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">* 2016 Internship Program update</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">* WBC Update-- First Reading Salon</a></li>
           <li style=" margin-top:190px; margin-left:180px;"><a href="http://www.molex.com/molex/home" style="color:white;">more>>></a></li>
    </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:110;">
      <button class="dropbtn"style="margin-left:250px;">Notice & Policy</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content"style="margin-left:215;">
     <h1 style="margin-left:50;">Cooperate news</h1>
      <ul style="float:left; margin-right:60%;margin-top:-10;line-height:2;list-style:none;">

      <li> <a href="http://www.molex.com/molex/home"> *How connected cars are turning into revenue-generating machines - August 29, 2016</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">*Delphu, Mobileye Join Forces to Develop Selfdrive System - August 23,2016</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">*MIT Spinoff to Market Breakthrough Batteries by 2017 - August 22,2016</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">*Cisco Cuts Workforce by 7 percent to Speed Transition to Software - August 18, 2016</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1 style="margin-left:490; margin-top:-60;">Chengdu News</h1>
      <ul style="margin-left: 55%; margin-top:-396;float:left; line-height:2;list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <a href="#">* 10 Year Service Award ceremony</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">* PDP Training</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">* ISO 27001 project Kick-off</a></li>
           <li> <a href="#">* 2016 Internship Program update</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">* WBC Update-- First Reading Salon</a></li>
           <li style=" margin-top:190px; margin-left:180px;"><a href="http://www.molex.com/molex/home" style="color:white;">more>>></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:220;">
  <button class="dropbtn"style="margin-left:292px;">Workflow & MIS</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content"style="margin-left:105;">
     <h1 style="margin-left:50;">Online Workflow:</h1>


   <ul style="float:left; margin-right:60%;margin-top:-10;line-height:2;list-style:none">

  <li> <a href="#"> MII</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">APS WF Reports</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">PAR Apply (TIS)</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">PAR Applcation (CCS)</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">PAR Application (DSS)<a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Company Chop Application<a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Facility Maintenance<a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Cycle Count Review<a></li>
</ul>
<h1 style="margin-left:490; margin-top:-60;">MIS:</h1>
  <ul style="margin-left: 55%; margin-top:-270;float:left; line-height:2;list-style:none;">
  <li>
    <a href="#">User ID Application</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Meeting room Booking Guide</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">How to apply mass SAS</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Office 365 -email- retention policy</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">How to report con-call issue or problem to Level 3</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:410;">
  <button class="dropbtn"style="width:120px;height:95px;margin-left:254px;margin-top:0px;background-color:#e6e6e6;"></button>
 <img src="molex.png" alt="molex" height="30px" width="100px" style="margin-top: 45; position:fixed; z-index:1;margin-left:268;">
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:451;">
  <button class="dropbtn"style="margin-left:334px;">Canteen</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content"style="margin-left:-126;">
    <h1 style="margin-left:50;">Menu Today</h1>
  <ul style="float:left; margin-right:60%;margin-top:-10;line-height:2;list-style:none; color:white;">
<img src="logo update.jpg">
  <li>  Lunch:</li>
    <li >Dinner:</li>
   <li > Midnight:</li>

</ul>
<h1 style="margin-left:466; margin-top:-56; font-size:28px;">Canteen Committee:</h1>

<h1 style="margin-left:465; margin-top:-102px;float:left;">Advices:</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:562;">
  <button class="dropbtn"style="margin-left:375px;">Activity & Organization</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content"style="margin-left:-237;">
    <h1 style="margin-left:50;">Activity</h1>
  <ul style="float:left; margin-right:60%;margin-top:-10;line-height:2;list-style:none">

  <li> <a href="#">Family day</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photography Contest</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">Talent show</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Singing Contest</a></li>
</ul>
<h1 style="margin-left:490; margin-top:-60;">Organization</h1>
  <ul style="margin-left: 55%; margin-top:-144;float:left; line-height:2;list-style:none;">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Walfare Committee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Badminton Club</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">Photography Club</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Riding Club</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Dancing Club</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Women's Business Committee (WBC)</a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Corporate Social Responsibility (CSR)</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-left:672;">
  <button class="dropbtn"style="margin-left:417px;">Culture</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content"style="margin-left:-347;">
     <h1 style="margin-left:50;">MBM Column</h1>
  <ul style="float:left; margin-right:60%;margin-top:-10;line-height:2;list-style:none">

  <li> <a href="#">Introduction of MBM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MBM Materials</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">MBM in Chengdu</a></li>
       </ul>
<h1 style="margin-left:490; margin-top:-60;">Molex Chengdu</h1>
  <ul style="margin-left: 448px; margin-top:-114px;float:left; line-height:2;list-style:none;">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">10 Year Anniversary Magazine</a></li>
   <li><a href="等等等等等等.htm" target='_blank' 
title="Click here to open a Word document">
Click here to open a Word document</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
</div>





<ul class="cb-slideshow">
    <li>
        <span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div></li>
    <li><span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div></li>
        <li>
        <span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="molex" height="100%" width="100%"> 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<h1 style="position:fixed;z-index:1; margin-top:40%;margin-left:30%;"><div id="clockbox" style=""> </div></h1>




<script>

= 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

var today = new Date();
 document.getElementById('time').innerHTML=today;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yvkdt64o/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach could be to achieve the hover effect via CSS and the click behaviour through JS, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my_button').click(function() {
      if ( $('.my_tooltip').css('display') === 'block' ) {
        $('.my_tooltip').css('display','block');
      }           
     });
});
```

```css
.my_button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.my_tooltip {
  display: none;
  background-color: Wheat;
  min-width: 160px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.my_button:hover {
  background-color: #F28686;
}

.my_button:hover + .my_tooltip{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
  <button class="my_button">Here</button>
  
  <div class="my_tooltip"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi auctor, dui eu maximus maximus, lacus nulla ornare magna, sit amet ullamcorper enim sapien eget felis. Nam aliquet ultricies eros aliquam pellentesque.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The codes posted along with your question doesn't really point out your issue (what button and what div) but a simple open `div` on `click` with `javascript` would be

if `div` by default is `display: none`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
       $('div').fadeIn(); //could be a .show() or .css("display", "block")
    });
});
```

if they are links you `.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.button').click(function() {
       $('div').fadeIn(); //could be a .show() or .css("display", "block")
    });
});
```